# kobuki_keyop, keyop.launch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch kobuki_keyop keyop.launch
I want to write a python code to replace keyop.launch. However, it doesn't go well. I think it is wrong with the way to send the message of keyboardinput. How can I solve the problem. I can compile the code. Please help me.

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('kobuki_keyop')

from kobuki_msgs.msg import KeyboardInput

import rospy

#import KeyboardInput                                                          

from std_msgs.msg import String

#from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist                                           

def key():

 rospy.init_node("keyop")

 pub1 = rospy.Publisher("keyop/motor_power",KeyboardInput)

 pub1 = rospy.Publisher("mobile_base/commands/motor_power",KeyboardInput)

 pub2 = rospy.Publisher("keyop/cmd_vel",KeyboardInput)

 while not rospy.is_shutdown():

  str = KeyboardInput()

  linear_vel = KeyboardInput()

  angular_vel = KeyboardInput()

  print str

  pub1.publish(linear_vel)

  pub2.publish(angular_vel)

  rospy.sleep(1.0)

 　rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     key()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196889/kobuki_keyop,-keyop.launch/) by [Kuniaki Saito](https://answers.ros.org/users/20511/kuniaki-saito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you don't seem to have any keyboard callback function. linear_vel = KeyboardInput() will not take your keyboard input.
If you check the [cpp implementation of Kobuki teleop](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/blob/indigo/kobuki_keyop/src/keyop_core.cpp) you can see that there is a function dedicated to detecting the user's input. For simplicity you could use cv2.WaitKey function from openCV in your code instead.

Here is the keyboard input detection function from cpp

```
void KeyOpCore::keyboardInputLoop()
{
struct termios raw;
memcpy(&raw, &original_terminal_state, sizeof(struct termios));
raw.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
// Setting a new line, then end of file
raw.c_cc[VEOL] = 1;
raw.c_cc[VEOF] = 2;
tcsetattr(key_file_descriptor, TCSANOW, &raw);
puts("Reading from keyboard");
puts("---------------------------");
puts("Forward/back arrows : linear velocity incr/decr.");
puts("Right/left arrows : angular velocity incr/decr.");
puts("Spacebar : reset linear/angular velocities.");
puts("d : disable motors.");
puts("e : enable motors.");
puts("q : quit.");
char c;
while (!quit_requested)
{
if (read(key_file_descriptor, &c, 1) < 0)
{
perror("read char failed():");
exit(-1);
}
processKeyboardInput(c);
}
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0